# Right exact sequence and exact functors

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I'm wondering if we have a left exact sequence $ 0 \rightarrow E \rightarrow F \rightarrow G$ of objects, and an exact functor  *T* from some abelian category $A$ to $Com(A)$.

Can we have something similar to a long exact sequence of homology or cohomology?

I'm especially interested in the case that $T(F)$ and $T(G)$ are exact complexes.

Thank you!

Comment: I see your point. But can E be an acyclic complex if $G$ and $F$ are acyclic?

Comment: You have an exact sequence $0 \to E \to F \to G \to G/F \to 0$, and applying $T$ preserves it, giving an exact sequence $0 \to T(E) \to T(F) \to T(G) \to T(G/F) \to 0$. What else is there to say?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I just corrected the exercise.

Comment: My question is : If $T(F)$ and $T(G)$ are exact, then $T(E)$ is exact?

Comment: By exact do you mean acyclic?

Comment: $0 \to E \to F \to G$ is exact on the left, not on the right.

Comment: Yes acyclic Yuan.

Comment: Yes Hurkyl, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Theorem:** If
>
> - $0 \to A \to B \to C \to D \to 0$ is an exact sequence of complexes,
> - $B$ is an exact complex, and
> - $C$ is an exact complex,
>
> then $H_n(A) \cong H_{n+2}(D)$.

I like to approach problems by looking at the corresponding bicomplex. You can usually learn a lot from the two spectral sequences for computing its total homology.

In the spectral sequence where you take horizontal homology first, the $E^1$ page looks like
$$ \begin{matrix}
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{matrix} $$
because every row is exact. Thus, the total homology is zero.

In the spectral sequence where you take vertical homology first, the $E^1$ page looks like

$$ \begin{matrix}
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\\ H_3(A) & 0 & 0 & H_3(D)
\\ H_2(A) & 0 & 0 & H_2(D)
\\ H_1(A) & 0 & 0 & H_1(D)
\\ H_0(A) & 0 & 0 & H_0(D) 
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{matrix} $$

Since the total homology is zero, the groups in the above diagram have to eventually be eliminated as you step through the spectral sequence. There is only one possibility for there to be differentials — in the $E^3$ page, where the differentials go 3 steps right and 2 steps up.

Since the homology has to be zero, the differentials have to be isomorphisms.

---

I posted the above since the proof technique is powerful enough that one should learn it! However, there is a more elementary method available: you can split the exact sequence into two short exact sequences

$$ 0 \to A \to B \to E \to 0 \qquad 0 \to E \to C \to D \to 0 $$

and the long exact sequence in homology shows

$$ H_n(A) \cong H_{n+1}(E) \cong H_{n+2}(D) $$

Comment: Do you know a book on spectral sequences?